# Allow users in chroot to SSH to another VM instance

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

Been coming across some issues with setting up SSH from a chroot directory out to a secondary VM. This is all being done in Google Cloud at the moment using CentOS 8. I think I have created the chroot directory correctly, added `/bin/ssh` to the chroot directory, added shared libraries for `/bin/ssh`.

I am stuck currently at running `ssh <IP_ADDRESS>`. I had to first create a `/home/<USER>/.ssh` in the chroot, then I added a `known_hosts` file inside `.ssh`. I connected to the second VM and can see that a host was added to the `known_hosts` file but I cannot get past an error about `<USER>@<IP_ADDRESS> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Password authentication is disabled currently in `sshd_config` on both VM instances. I remember briefly trying password authentication with both and it still failed. I am not sure of what I am missing to resolve this.

Comment: To login to a remote machine with SSH key pairs requires placing the public key on the remote host and the private key on the local host. Did you do that?

Comment: Thanks, yes that was part of the problem. Manually created a SSH key pair on the Bastion, was able to get the public key to the second instance and private key was added to the chroot directory. I also needed to add a `/tmp` folder to my chroot directory along with `/bin/ssh-add` and `/bin/ssh-agent` along with associated shared libraries (ldd) for ssh-add and ssh-agent.